# Check if internet is available

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to check for an active Internet Connection on iPhone SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk)

I need to check the internet reachability before sending a request to fetch something remotely.
I googles, and found several SO questions relating to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083701/how-to-check-for-an-active-internet-connection-on-iphone-sdk). But i need to check internet connectivity for iOS4 and iOS5. How can i do that programatically ?

2.) For example say i am downloading a big file (when there was internet). and suddenly the Internet goes down (Then the app might crash). So how can i avoid this ?

Comment: The Apple's Reachability class is the answer, as you've seen in the link you are referring to.

Comment: The problem is, if it'll work for iOS 5. if you look close at @AndrewZimmer's answer he has not used Reachability class in his code. And he has tested it on iOS5. I need a method that will work both for iOS 4 & 5.

Comment: It works very well on iOS 5. Just try, and you'll see by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Download Reachability from [Apple Site](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

```
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
remoteHostStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (remoteHostStatus != NotReachable) {
     // do work here if the user has a valid connection
}
```

Comment: When providing an answer, please pay attention to formatting... At least...

Comment: Will this work for both iOS4 & 5 ? because the ref doc hasn't mentioned anything about iOS5. it talks about iOS 4 but not 5.